# django rest api doest not retrive data from my database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, geodjango

i am trying to retrieve data from my django database using django rest framework but my api view showa no data.

models.py

```
class shop(models.Model):
    spname = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=" ")
    spownm = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=" ")
    mob = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = GeoManager()
```

views.py

```
class shoplist(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = shop.objects.all()
   serializer_class = shopSerializers
```

serializers.py

```
class shopSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = shop
      fields = ('spname', 'spownm', 'mob', 'location')
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'^', views.shoplist)
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^categories/(?P<Catg_id>[0-9])/(?P<Type_id>[0-9]+)/shops/', include(router.urls)),
 ]
```

my result with above api is

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{}
```

it shows no data while i expect it to list the items in database.

Comment: Are you sure that you have some rows in your table? Could you show us some of the items on your DB?

Comment: yes i do have 2 rows in my table in postgresql @laviande22

Comment: are you connected to same db you have data within? Can you check settings and confirm? Also please try to use pascal casing while naming class based views

Comment: What url are you hitting?

Comment: @akhilsuresh yes I am connected to the same database as the one I am trying to get data from.